# How to check the entire state of a form in react, in order to enable a disabled button submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom, onchange

I have a onChange event in react that is populating state correctly. I am disabling the form button when there is a empty field on submit. However I want them to be able to go back and fill out that field, or two (which is the key sticking point) and if both fields have some data to enable the form again.

Here is my state

```
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    package: `${data.datoCmsPricing.title}`,
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
    "reasons": {
      "weightLoss": false,
      "strength": false,
      "sport": false,
   }
  })
```

Here is my onChange, currently at the name validation, **I can only target the input that is selected. I want to check the entire forms state if empty or not on change event and then enable the button.**

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {

      const changedReason = e.target.getAttribute('name');
      setFormState({...formState, reasons:{...formState.reasons, [changedReason]: !formState.reasons[changedReason]}});
      //setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked});
      console.log(formState);
    } else {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    }

    //name validation  
    if (e.target.name.value === "") {
      setShowMessageName(true)
      setFormInvalid(false)

    }
    else{
      setShowMessageName(false)
      setFormInvalid(true)
    }

 }
```

Here is my Form Validation States

```
//Form Errors and Hiding and Showing


const [form, setForm] = useState(true);

function showForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setForm(true);
}

const [formFail, setFormFail] = useState(true);

function formFailReset(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setFormFail(true);
}

const [formInvalid, setFormInvalid] = useState(true);

function formInactive(){

}

// const [nameVal, setNameVal] = useState(false);


const [showMessageName, setShowMessageName] = useState(false)

const [showMessageEmail, setShowMessageEmail] = useState(false)

//End
```

Here is my submit

```
 const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  //name validation  
  if (e.target.name.value === "") {
    setShowMessageName(true)
    setFormInvalid(false)

  }
  else{
    setShowMessageName(false)
    setFormInvalid(true)
  }
  //email validation
  if (e.target.email.value === "") {
    setShowMessageEmail(true)
  }
  else{
    setShowMessageEmail(false)
  }

  ...
```

Here is my Form

```
<PackageForm onChange={formOnChange} onSubmit={submitForm}>
      {/* <input type="text" name="package" value={data.datoCmsPricing.title} /> */}
      <label>
        <h3>Name{ showMessageName && <span> *Required</span>}</h3>     
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formState.name}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <h3>Email{ showMessageEmail && <span> *Required</span>}</h3>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formState.email}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="subject"
          value={formState.subject}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <div>
      <h3>Reasons for wanting to train</h3>
      <CheckBoxes>

        <label>
        <h4>Weight Loss</h4>
        <div class="pretty p-default">
          <input 
            type="checkbox"
            name="weightLoss"
            reason="Weight Loss"
            checked={formState.reasons.weightLoss}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <div class="state p-primary">
            <label></label>
          </div>
        </div>

        </label>
        <label>
        <h4>Strength</h4> 
        <div class="pretty p-default">
          <input 
            type="checkbox"
            name="strength"
            reason="Strength"
            checked={formState.reasons.strength}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <div class="state p-primary">
            <label></label>
          </div>
        </div>

        </label>
        <label>
        <h4>Sport</h4> 
        <div class="pretty p-default">
          <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="sport"
          reason="Sport"
          checked={formState.reasons.sport}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <div class="state p-primary">
            <label></label>
          </div>
        </div>

        </label>
      </CheckBoxes>
      </div>

      <div className="text-area">
        <label>
          <h3>Message</h3>
          <textarea
            name="message"
            value={formState.message}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>

      {formFail ? 
        <label className= {formInvalid ? `submitHand` : `submitHand fail`}  >

          {formInvalid ? 
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          :
            <button disabled type="submit">See Required Fields</button>
          }

        </label>

      :
      <label className="submitHand fail">
        <span>Something Went Wrong</span>
        <a onClick={formFailReset} href="#">Click to reset form</a>
        <button disabled type="submit">Submit</button>
      </label>

      }


    </PackageForm>
```

**The most minimal of example I could think of.**

instead of the input itself being checked onChange I want the entire form, so what the value of input 1,2,3,4 is and if they all have data then enable the button. The if statement in that case would be like.

```
const onChangeEntireForm = (e) => {

    if (e.target.email.value === "" && e.target.name.value...) {
      console.log("keep button disabled");

    }
    else{
      console.log("enable button");
    }
}
```

what I currently have that doesnt work, because it is only checking the input one at a time, not each input 1,2,3,4 or email, name...

```
const onChange = (e) => {

    //name validation  
    if (e.target.name.value === "") {
      console.log("keep button disabled");

    }
    else{
      console.log("enable button");
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example, as this code is way too thorough for future generations to benefit from

Comment: oh man that's what I was going to do, and then I thought I would be docked for not explaining well enough. Let me add a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the state to check the validation. This way you can access all the form data at once. For example:

```
const checkValidation = () => {
  const required = ['email','subject','message'];
  const invalid = required.some(key => formState[key] === '')
  setShowMessageName(!invalid)
  setFormInvalid(invalid)
}
```

So you can check the validation in onChange.

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {

      const changedReason = e.target.getAttribute('name');
      setFormState({...formState, reasons:{...formState.reasons, [changedReason]: !formState.reasons[changedReason]}});
      //setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked});
      console.log(formState);
    } else {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    }

    //name validation  
    checkValidation();
 }
```

Is it your problem?

Comment: Sort of helps simplify what I was doing, but the issue is it still enables the button when one input is valid, or filled. Where I only want to enable the button if the all inputs are valid or filled or !empty. I am gonna fiddle with your code more tho.

Comment: If instead of checking the key I just grab the whole formState and write if statments with a `&&` seprator for each field I think it will work.

Comment: It should only set validity if none of the field in required is empty.

Comment: My solution is just an example how a validation should work. I hope it is a good starting point.